# Ruby on Rails: how to parse a JSON string that may or may not contain an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am querying a song database in Rails. If the song appeared on more than one album the result is an array. If the song appeared on only one album, there isn't an array. Here are snippets from the results:

Array of results:

```
"title"=>"Kokomo Blues",
"artist_name"=>"Mississippi Fred McDowell",
"tracks"=>
[{"album_type"=>"other",
"id"=>"TRGBEVE12EFD5C030F"},
{"album_type"=>"other",
"id"=>"TRAJQGU12EFD5C02FB"}]
```

Single result:

```
"title"=>"Most Things Haven't Worked Out",
"artist_name"=>"Junior Kimbrough",
"tracks"=>
{"album_type"=>"other",
"id"=>"TRGBEVE12EFD5C030F"}
```

My question - how do I parse the "id" from the JSON result when I don't know if an array is present or not?

Answer (score 0):

Single...

```
> h = {}
> h['tracks'] = {"album_type"=>"other","id"=>"TRGBEVE12EFD5C030F"}
=> {"album_type"=>"other", "id"=>"TRGBEVE12EFD5C030F"}

> [h['tracks']].flatten.map{|e| e['id']}
=> ["TRGBEVE12EFD5C030F"]
```

Multiple...

```
> h = {}
> h['tracks'] = [{"album_type"=>"other", "id"=>"TRGBEVE12EFD5C030F"},
                 {"album_type"=>"other", "id"=>"TRAJQGU12EFD5C02FB"}]
=> [{"album_type"=>"other", "id"=>"TRGBEVE12EFD5C030F"},
    {"album_type"=>"other", "id"=>"TRAJQGU12EFD5C02FB"}]

> [h['tracks']].flatten.map{|e| e['id']}
=> ["TRGBEVE12EFD5C030F", "TRAJQGU12EFD5C02FB"]
```